# Simple javascript regex help needed

Tags: regex

I have an regex expression:

```
\[quote\](.*?)\[\/quote\]
```

and it matches correctly between [quote]example[/quote] but it does not find a match for:

```
[quote]
example

[/quote]
```

how can I change the regex so it finds a match in the latter case too? *And keeps the format (multiple lines)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [\r\n]* to the regular expressiuon

```
\[quote\](.*?)\[\r\n]*[\/quote\]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in JavaScript the `.` does not match a new line (and this cannot be changed unlike in other languages where you might use the `s` modifier). So the following should work:

```
\[quote\]([\s\S]*?)\[\/quote\]
```

`\s` will match every whitespace character (including new lines) and `\S` will match every non-whitespace character - together `[\s\S]` matches every character including new lines.

Comment: Works, but keeps it on all one line, I want it to still have the same layout.